# Stumped!!! Teradata SQL. How do I pull MIN/MAX values from a history table for each group change with repeating groups over time?

Tags: sql, max, teradata, min

I'm pulling a subset of columns from a history table (effective dated) but need to condense so only the changes to the relevant values are displayed.  I need to condense because the history table tracks column changes day over day and has a new row for any column change in the table. See Below sorted result set.  I need to pull MIN(eff_dt) MAX(exp_dt) each time email changes.

```
ID EMAIL EFF_DT EXP_DT 
486007909 ? 7/22/2009 7/22/2009
486007909 ? 7/23/2009 7/23/2009
486007909 B@L.COM 7/24/2009 8/2/2009
486007909 B@L.COM 8/3/2009 8/10/2009
486007909 B@L.COM 8/11/2009 9/6/2013
486007909 ? 9/7/2013 10/22/2014
486007909 ? 10/23/2014 11/3/2014
486007909 B@L.COM 11/4/2014 12/1/2016
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: Expected result from data above is the min eff_dt and max exp dt  for each group from the top, these four rows: Expected result from data above is the min eff_dt and max exp dt  for each group from the top, these four rows: 486007909 ? 7/22/2009 7/23/2009; 486007909 B@L.COM 7/24/2009 9/6/2013; 486007909 ? 9/7/2013 11/3/2014; 486007909

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a gap and islands problem.  You can use the difference of row number in this case:

```
select id, email, min(eff_dt), max(exp_dt)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by eff_dt) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by id, email order by eff_dt) as seqnum_e
      from t
     ) t
group by email, (seqnum - seqnum_e);
```

Answer (score 1):

Teradata has a proprietary extension for normalizing overlapping periods:

```
SELECT id, email
  -- split the period back into seperate columns
  ,Begin(pd)
  -- reverts NEXT = last included date
  ,Last(pd)
FROM
 ( -- NORMALIZE works on periods only
   SELECT NORMALIZE id, email,
      -- periods include begin, but exclude end
      -- modify end_dt accordingly
      PERIOD(eff_dt, NEXT(exp_dt)) AS pd
   FROM tab
 ) AS dt
```

Comment: dnoeth, The normalize function is exactly what I need.  Worked like a charm.  Never used or heard of it before, so thanks so much for the knowledge.  Appreciate all other answers as well.  Let's keep the learning going.